# How can I turn off Wifi using cordova?

Tags: cordova, oracle-maf

I found that we can turn on/off wifi in native android using WifiManager class like this:

> WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
> this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
>
> wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
>
> wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

As we all knows that cordova is used to access device's native features then is it possible using cordova to turn on/off wifi programmatically?

Comment: Just use a suitable Cordova pluogin. Ex: https://github.com/parsonsmatt/WifiWizard